# watIn - working with timer in winform

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, watin

im using WatiN for app im working on. in the app i got a list of sites: `List<string> sites;`

and i got a timer that im runing every few second to load and send data or get data from the current site.

when i try runing this code nothing happend, not even Exception. i have no idea why.

```
private void watiNMethod()
    {
        Settings.AutoStartDialogWatcher = false;

                Settings.AutoStartDialogWatcher = false;
                ie = new IE(webBrowser1.ActiveXInstance);

                ie.GoTo(sites[runing]);
                ie.WaitForComplete();
                MessageBox.Show("done loading");
    }

    int runing;
    Thread watInThread;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

        timer.Start();

        watInThread = new Thread(watiNMethod);
        watInThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

        runing = 0;

    }

    private void timer_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (runing <= sites.Count)
        {
            watInThread.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            timer.Stop();
        }

        runing++;
    }
```

i want to be able to load to the web browser control, wait for him to complete with WatiN methods, and send data to the site or just get data from him.

im not sure how do this, becuse i have to use Thread to run WatiN inside the `WebBrowswer` Control.

(sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're setting timer.Tick?!?

```
timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
timer.Tick += new EventHandler(this.timer_tick);
timer.Start();
```